# HTTP server for testing all HTTP verbs

Tags: python, unit-testing, webserver

I am developing an library for consuming RESTful webservices in a graphical programming language.

I try to unit test all components via starting up the interpreter for this language and comparing the output to console via python, which is working quite well for other parts of the library, but not for components that consume RESTful webservices.

Is there a lightweight webserver that:

- is starting fast
- can easily be configured and setup
- implements all HTTP verbs, including esoteric ones like TRACE
- can deal with different request headers
- runs as a stand alone application
- runs on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux

The implementation of the component itself is done in C and uses libcurl for HTTP requests.

My main problem is finding an implementation of esoteric HTTP verbs, especially TRACE, as I have only read about it in standard documents, but have not found any real life example on either

- a server that responds to TRACE requests or
- an example for using libcurl to do TRACE requests.

So far I have looked into [web.py](http://webpy.org/) and [itty](https://github.com/toastdriven/itty), but neither implements TRACE.

I am not limited to python, as long as the hard requirements are fulfilled.

Comment: In Flask, the request method is simply a string being passed to the response handler. I haven't tested it, but I would guess it should be able to handle any method this way. Furthermore, Flask comes with unit testing classes based on Python standards: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/.